# Rails no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Thanks guys. I've solved the problem. It's because when I enter the `posts/new` page. The new action creates a dummy `@post` with nil attributes. Since the `@post` exists, the edit & delete link in the sidebar appears. However, the `edit_post_path` doesn't work because the `@post.id` is `nil`. Then the error occurs. So I just changed `<% if @post %>` to `<% if @post && !@post.id.nil?  %>` and it works.  -- p.s. The rails error message is quite confusing.**

I'm new to rails and just built a simple app and saw the error when I click a link to create a new post:
`No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}`

The `rake routes` result:

```
posts GET    /posts(.:format)              posts#index
      POST   /posts(.:format)              posts#create
new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)          posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)     posts#edit
 post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)          posts#show
      PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)          posts#update
      DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)          posts#destroy
```

The routes.rb file has `resources :posts` in it.

The link is : `<li><%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path %></li>`

The new & edit method in `PostsController`:

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I can show the post, edit the post and delete the post. But whenever I want to click the link to create a new post, the error occurs. I can't figure out why the `new_post_path` will leads to 'edit' path????

Could someone help me with this? If you need more codes plz tell me.

Thank you!

**UPDATES**

1. Add the _sidebar.html.erb (sorry for the format, idk how to keep them as original, there are some normal `nav`, `ul`, `li` tags outside)

   - <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
   - <%= link_to "About Me", about_path %>
     <% if signed_in? %>
   - <%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path %>
     <% if @post %>
   - <%= link_to "Edit Post", edit_post_path %>
   - <%= link_to "Delete Post", post_path(@post), method: "delete", confirm: "Are you sure to delete?" %>
     <% end %>
   - <%= link_to "Sign Out", chulai_path, method: "delete" %>
     <% end %>
2. The new.html.erb

   `<%= form_for @post do |f| %>`
      `<div class="field">`
         `<%= f.text_field :title %>`
      `</div>`

   ```
   <div class="field">
       <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "new post here..." %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
       <%= f.select :public, [['Public', true], ['Private', false]] %>
   </div>

   <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn" %>
   ```

   `<% end %>`
3. I tried `app.new_post_path`, it shows `/posts/new`, i guess it's good.

Comment: add more details or copy your view file plz

Comment: Actually the problem is with _form.html.erb. please add that file also.

Comment: I agree. Also please post new.html.erb, for just in case to have all clear

Comment: Put `app.new_post_path` in your console and see what it gives you.  If it gives you a path for edit, then the issue is in your routing somewhere.  If it gives you the correct route, orders/new, then you might have cache problem.

Comment: So then, at the end, the answer suggested was good. I said "It is complaining about no route matches as you haven't passed id of the edit post" Could you mark the answer as "answered". I don't care about the points, just to make it clearer for others if they run onto the same problem.

Comment: Actually the error you are saying about edit_post_path , is not correct, it should be edit_post_path(@post), that why it complained and showed the error, and @post.id = nil error would appear for delete post - post_path(@post). But the answer is the same - to use !@post.id.nil?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably using `edit_post_path` in your `new.html.erb` for posts.
It is complaining about `no route matches` as you haven't passed id of the edit post. But that shouldn't be in `new` view in the first place, so you probably need to delete that line - for editing post

Comment: If it's that case, edit post will only be come after you submit the form but not on link click.

Comment: what did you meant by "edit post will only be come after" ? What it will become after? And what if he is using edit_post_path(@post) in his new view?

Comment: If he is using something like `form_for @post, edit_post_path` in his new view, then it's meant for after form submit but since you haven't submitted the form yet, its useless at this point that the OP is getting error because of form.

Comment: yes, but he is probably not using it :) ok, I figured out that it is pointless to discuss before he posts his _form_html.erb file or new.html.erb, if he is using all in one file.

Comment: no, the comment is pointless. The answer might actually direct him to the solution.

Comment: there is nothing to see in `new.html.erb` as its just a view and what you write there does not direct the user to edit path at all.

Comment: see, why I said it is pointless to comment. Answer me this question: what will happen if he puts edit_user_path(@user) in his new.html.erb ?

Comment: If he puts this in `new.html.erb`, he will be redirected to edit post path after form submit. So obviously this is not the answer of OP's question because he is getting redirect to edit before form submit although your point is well noted but does not resolve/help what he want.

Comment: ok, sorry, I meant if he puts <%= link_to "Edit post", edit_user_path(@user) %>  in new.html.erb and not form_for @post, edit_post_path(@user). then it will be invoked on click action, which he is doing :) . Ok, stackoverflow is saying "Please avoid extended discussions in comments." so this will be my last comment. I will update the answer if needed, once he adds new code. But thanks for discussion, I appreciate the help.

Comment: I think he puts edit_post_path() without instance object otherwise the error should be something like: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil or #..}

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
edit_post_path(@post)
```

Comment: The error now shows: `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts", :id=>#<Post id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, public: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}`